# Bootstrap Process not Working with Directory Variables?

Tags: bootstrap

I have an external PHP script that tries to bootstrap Civi. When I use variables for Directories (like [cms.root]), the boostrap process gives me the following error. I have tried this with both "civi_boostrap()" and with the three-line method:

```
require_once $civi_path . '/civicrm.config.php';
require_once 'CRM/Core/Config.php';
$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
```

I cannot use the cv method, as I'm also bootstrapping WordPress, and the cv Drupal bootstrap conflicts with the WP functions (timer_start conflicts).

What's the best way to resolve this?

Here is the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path" in /var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Paths.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Paths.php(213): Civi\Core\Paths->getVariable('cms.root', 'path')
#1 /var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config/Runtime.php(122): Civi\Core\Paths->getPath('sites/all/civi_...')
#2 /var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(561): CRM_Core_Config_Runtime->includeCustomPath()
#3 /var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(93): Civi\Core\Container::boot(true)
```

Comment: What is you Civi version? Are you trying to use Civi from drupal? Is your $civi_path set to '/var/www/example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm'?

Comment: @PradeepNayak, Civi version is 5.35.1. I'm bootstrapping Civi from within a Drupal directory, yes. And yes, $civi_path is set to that path. Thanks.